# Virtual subdomain using htacess, Pages rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have make virtual subdomain in my code.like below

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mysitename\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ agent.php?asitename=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

it works fine, but it did not work for pages like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mysitename\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ag_buy.html ag_buy.php?sitename=%1&page=buy [L,NC,QSA]
```

it redirect all pages top agent.php, but it should only redirect home page to agent.php, for other pages it should work like ag_buy.html to ag_buy.php

and so on.........

please guide me on htaccess how can i make this possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the first rule with following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.).mysitename.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/
RewriteRule ^(.)$ agent.php?asitename=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `^(.*)$` matches *everything*, if you only want the home page, then change it to `^$`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mysitename\.com
RewriteRule ^$ agent.php?asitename=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: your code works, but for next page buy.php what i can add in htaccess file, ? like i have lee.sitename.com/2013/rss/ to rss.php?year=2013 so for this rule how can i implement ?

Comment: @user2341915 that doesn't look anything like your other "buy" stuff from your question, have you worked out how all of these things are supposed to map to each other? There can't be *any* overlapping.

Comment: I mean for this url, lee.sitename.com/2013/rss/ to rss.php?year=2013, what will be the htaccess rule ?

Comment: @user2341915 depends on what parts of the URI is abstracted, or is it only **2013** and only **rss**, and nothing else? If any of it is variable, how does that fit the "buy" stuff that you've got? And is the `lee` part not part of this equation anymore?

Comment: lee will go like %1, as it comes from subdomain, for other parts after subdomain url, is concerned.